# anchor tag in navigation is causing hover color not to work

Tags: css, hover, anchor

I have included a jsfiddle to show you an example. I have the navigation ul items set with a white background and the font is a red color. When hovered over I want the two colors to swap, the background to become the red color and the font to become white. Before I put the anchor tags in it worked, but after the font does not change to the white color on hover. If I add this:

```
nav ul li a:hover{
    color:white;
}
```

the font will change to white, but not when the box is hovered on, but only when the font itself is hovered on, but I want the font to change to white as the list item box is hovered on. Any help? Thanks!

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xNZxF/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this:

```
nav ul li:hover a{
    color:white;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xNZxF/1/)**

To match the easing you may want to also add `-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;` to `nav ul a`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xNZxF/3/)**

Comment: Is there a way to get the anchor tag to span the whole width of the li box? It seems to only click to the next page when the text is clicked and not the li box that is 140px in that jsfiddle example. If I wrap the a tag outside the li it throws a validation error in chrome

Comment: You'd need to change them to `display:block` and then alter their height or padding.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to your CSS.

```
nav ul li:hover > a {
    color: white;
}
```

Also remove `color: white;` from `nav ul li:hover`. You where trying to change the text color of the text within the `li` while it was actually in the `a`. With `nav ul li:hover > a` you can change the color of `a` when the `nav ul li` is being hovered over. This doesn't give the text a fancy transition to it's hover color, but I think you can figure that out by yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: white;
}
```